# What do you mean by 'make' command in linux?

Tags: build, linux-kernel, cluster-computing, vmware-workstation

First, i know that `make` is used for building the code. But which code?

But what does it mean by building a code, and after executing the `make` command, what is presented to the user?

Second, how is it different from `make build_for_e2e`?

Comment: Do you have some context or something?

Comment: No, i was working on my workstation awhile back and I started thinking about what is the point on executing it?

Comment: And the [Wikipedia page on Make](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)) didn't answer your question?

Comment: no, it says "it automatically builds executable programs and libraries from source code" i am not able to get this part. which source code is it talking about?

Comment: The source code which some developer wrote? Sorry, I don't get that part of your question at all.

Comment: read the first line in [Make- Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)). Can you explain what does it mean?

Comment: It means what it says, `make` makes building ("compiling") sourcecode to executable programs easier.

Comment: which source code is it taking about?

Comment: The source code which someone wants to compile...

Comment: but we aren't specifying the source code. there can be may codes that i want to compile.

Comment: @RV186 Make isn't language-specific. You can use the Makefile to configure any compiler you might have installed on your system and use it to make the compiling process easier. So instead of `gcc -Wall hello.c -o hello`, or in some cases a much MUCH longer command, it becomes the simple `make`

Comment: @John, moreover, `make` **is** the functional language interpreter. And it doesn't mean it should or has to compile / build other's sources.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)) tells about make

> **Make is a build automation tool that automatically builds executable programs and libraries from source code**

Compilation process becomes big and complex in big projects, where numbers of files need to be compiled, with flags and libraries. Where it will become hard for people to compile it one by one. So these types of tools were introduced, there are more similar tools available for same use like cmake, gradle, maven. e2e's Build is also a form of build process, with different form of specifications.

For C people mostly use make. It is helpful for porting software packages in different systems.

How `make` is used:

As said `make` is a tool, which will be available in our system, we can execute it by giving command `make` in the directory which needs to be compiled. Then make looks for Makefile, which is provided in the package directory and it contains information about compilation of the project. Then `make` as per info gathered from Makefile, it compiles the package.

You can also create Makefile for your project, so that it can be also supported and compiled with `make`. Simple tutorial for it can be found [here](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/). For big projects you can use `gnu autotools` contains autoconf and automake which will help you to create your all files required by make automatically. You can find tutorial regarding it [here](http://www.dwheeler.com/autotools/) and [here](http://mij.oltrelinux.com/devel/autoconf-automake/) . These contains some basic information, you can find some advance tutorial regarding autotools, use google for more information on it.